# inserting data from a file in access table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a form in access with a button that lets user select a text file(file dialog). How can I insert the data from that selected file in a table?

Here is my code for selecting a file:

```
Sub InsertData()

Dim fDialog As Object  
 Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(1) 
with fDialog 
 .AllowMultiSelect = False
 .Show  
 End If 

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use [DoCmd.TransferText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214141%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: is there a way of dynamically identifying where the Column names start at Run Time? The file I am expecting may have column names starting at any random line. There would however be an indicator of where the column names starts. There will be a "Table Below" text right before the column names begin.

Comment: If the text file is not structured, I suggest you use something such as the FileSystemObject to get a textstream which you can loop through, you can either write the table data from the textstream to an Access table or you can save the relevant lines to another file and import that.